# Comic about a woman that turns invisible after falling into a pool

Tags: story-identification, comics

As a kid (90s), I read some comics about a woman who was an explorer of some sorts.

In one of them, she falls into a lava/magic pool that renders her invisible (she also becomes worshipped by a tribe of non-humans I think?)

In another, she ends up stranded on an island with dinosaurs.

**Edit:** The woman becoming invisible was not treated as a superpower (she couldn't turn it on/off) but as an ailment. Also, the woman's aspect was one of a young, slender girl with brown/red hair. The comic drawing style was not cartoonish (tending more to the realistic side)

Comment: This is pretty brief so if there is anything else you can remember please don't hesitate to [edit] it in. It might also be worthwhile taking a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can add.

Comment: How many women get superpowers by falling into lava? That's how [Firebrand](http://dcuguide.com/w/Firebrand_(Danette_Reilly)) got her powers too.

Comment: Possibly an European comic?

Comment: Just to rule out a particular segment of comics with female protagonists, this want an adult comic, was it?

Comment: @Jenayah I also think it may be an European comic, since the style seems similar to some examples i've seen, but i'm no expert in comics so i cannot be sure.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It wasn't a comic for kids, but it didn't treat adult themes like sex, drugs o extreme violence (maybe some partial nudity); i had borrowed it from my primary school's library.